# Wordpress won't update pages

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have got a web-site from my client where I can't update anything - it does the updates in admin panel, but not on user side. The web-site is filled with plugins including different cache modules which I deactivated - still no luck. I even change the homepage to a different page in settings but it shows me the page built with visual composer. These are the plugins that are currently active:

```
Addon Creator for Visual Composer - Null24.Net
Composium - Visual Composer Extensions Addon
DHVC Form-Null24.Net    
Elegant Mega Addons for Visual Composer
FormCraft - shared on Themelot.net
Global Gallery  
Image Map Pro
Justified Image Grid
LayerSlider WP  
Massive Addons for Visual Composer
Orbit
Simple Lightbox
STM Post Type
Templatera
TinyMCE Advanced    
UberMenu 3 - The Ultimate WordPress Mega Menu
Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer
Visual Composer Clipboard   
Visual Composer Extensions All In One
WP Floating Menu Pro
WPBakery Visual Composer
Yoast SEO Premium
```

I have deactivated these plugins that might be responsible:

```
WP-Optimize
WP Super Cache
WP-Offload
WP Rocket
W3 Total Cache
Hyper Cache (two of these)
Heartbeat Control
Autoptimize
```

And the full list of plugins:

```
Addon Creator for Visual Composer - Null24.Net
AJAX AutoSuggest
Akismet
Autoptimize
Black Studio TinyMCE Widget
Breadcrumb NavXT
BWL Knowledge Base Manager-Null24.Net
Category and Taxonomy Image
Check and Enable GZIP compression
Clearfy
Composium - Visual Composer Extensions Addon
Composium - Visual Composer Extensions Addon
ConvertPlug-Null24.Net
Custom Sidebars
DHVC Form-Null24.Net
Duplicator
DZS ZoomTabs and Accordions - shared on wplocker.com
Easy FancyBox
Easy Social Share Buttons for WordPress
Easy Tables (vc)
Elegant Mega Addons for Visual Composer
Force Regenerate Thumbnails
FormCraft - shared on Themelot.net
FormCraft reCaptcha Add-On
Global Gallery
Google Analytics by MonsterInsights Pro
Gravity Forms-Null24.Net
Heartbeat Control
Hello Dolly
Hybrid Gallery
Hyper Cache (3.2.6)
Hyper Cache (2.9.1.6)
If Modified Since
Image Map Pro
Indeed Social Share & Locker Pro (shared on wplocker.com)
Intense
Justified Image Grid
LayerSlider WP
Logos Showcase
Massive Addons for Visual Composer
Massive Addons for Visual Composer - Collections
Media Library Assistant
Mega Main Extensions
Orbit
Page Builder by SiteOrigin
PressApps Knowledge Base
Progress Map by CodeSpacing
PW News Ticker Post Layout For Visual Composer - shared on wplocker.com
Query Monitor
Real-time Visitor Stats for WordPress-Null24.Net
Schema Creator by Raven
Sidebar & Widget Manager
Simple Lightbox
Slider Pro
Slider Revolution
Speed Up WordPress Plugin - Null24.Net
STM Post Type
Super Forms - Drag & Drop Form Builder
Templatera
TinyMCE Advanced
UberMenu - Sticky Menu Extension
UberMenu 3 - The Ultimate WordPress Mega Menu
Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer
Ultimate Tweaker
Visual Composer Clipboard
Visual Composer Extensions - Popup, Notification and Gallery
Visual Composer Extensions All In One
Visual Composer Modal Popups
Visual Composer Popup Notifications
W3 Total Cache
Webnus Core
Webnus Shortcodes
WooCommerce
WordPress Gzip Compression
WP Floating Menu
WP Floating Menu Pro
WP HTTP Compression
WP Real Media Library
WP Resized Image Quality
WP Rocket
WP Smush
WP Smush Pro
WP Super Cache
WP-Offload
WP-Optimize
WPBakery Visual Composer (three of this v4.11, v4.11 and v5.0.1)
Yandex.Metrika
Yoast SEO Premium
Изображения таксономий
Прокрутка вверх
```

I know what it looks like, but I can't simply try removing the plugins as a web-site with the things like visual composer are extremely difficult to restore from backup. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Web-site url: http://diadel.ru

Comment: This are way too much Plugins for a single WordPress installation. Furthermore there is not a lot of sense in e.g. combining 6 different cache plugins which have the same purpose. This will SLOW your site instead of boosting.

However there can be much more reasons: Server caching, wrong environment, ...

Throw a PHP error in the template: Does it appear?

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. I found the problem - there was a static index.html file - probably the creator decided to create a static page in order to improve the speed. Didn't really help :)

Comment: Wow.... XD WordPress is not Lego you can not stuff in 50 plugins and expect it to work well en'